# Fibonacci number in product of prime form

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, prime-factorization

How do you find the primes factor of fibonacci number? I knew that every Fibonacci number bigger than 1 [except F(6)=8 and F(12)=144] has at least one prime factor that is not a factor of any earlier Fibonacci number.

For example $F_{19} = 37 * 113$

37 and 113 are prime but how do you find this pair of prime product of fibonacci number?

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm or a formula?

Comment: @OlivierRoche Just a formula

Comment: Then you're asking for the holy grail, I'm affraid

Comment: @OlivierRoche I just want to know if there is a "trivial" formula to find this. If not, that's fine.

Comment: There isn't as of today